# I'm in trouble. Decimal numbers don't come when I do math

Tags: numbers, decimal

```py
def call_result(label_result, n1, n2, n3):  
    num1 = (n1.get())  
    num2 = (n2.get())  
    num3 = (n3.get())
    num4 = 100
    num5 = 12
    num6 = 2

    main1 = float(int(num1))*float(int(num2)) / 12 / 2 / 100
    main2 = float(int(num1)) / float(int(num3))
    main3 = float(int(main2))+float(int(main1))
    
    label_result.config(text="Result = %d" % float(main3))  
    return
```

I'm in trouble. Decimal numbers don't come when I do math

The answer is supposed to be 20.84 but this code produces 20.

Comment: Please edit your question so that your physical code is listed instead of a link. Also, what do you mean by "Decimal numbers don't come"? What's the difference between your code's output and the expected output?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Done bro

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the conversion between int and float

Assuming the three nums are strings you should just convert them to float directly and skip the intermediate step.
Moreover when you convert from float to int and then back to float you lost the decimal data because int does not store it.

For example

```py
main2 = 23.34        # main2 is a float with value 23.34
main2 = int(main2)   # main2 is now an int with value 23 
                     # Remember int (short for integer) cannot store floating point values and will truncate the number to make an integer
main2 = float(main2) # main2 is now a float but the value is 23.0 because you lost the precision when it was converted to int
```

I recommend doing something like this

```py
def call_result(label_result, n1, n2, n3):  
    num1 = float(n1.get())  
    num2 = float(n2.get())  
    num3 = float(n3.get())
    num4 = 100
    num5 = 12
    num6 = 2

    main1 = num1 * num2 / 12 / 2 / 100
    main2 = num1 / num3
    main3 = main2 + main1

    label_result.config(text="Result = %.2f" % main3)  
    return
```

Another thing to take care of is the format specifier you use for the string. `%d` refers to an integer while `%f` is for floats. Even if `main3` was a float you would have ended up with an integer in your string.
`%.2f` will truncate a float to a precision of 2 decimal places

`"%.2f" % 123.45678` becomes `123.45`

Take a look at the [string formatting guide here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html)

Comment: Thank you very very much and its Works.@mudit-kapoo

Comment: @Imran123bd Please consider accepting the answer so that others see that the issue is resolved and so that they can find the correct answer more easily.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I'm new.. Sorry bro.